# How to create a message when comment is voted?

Tags: 10, message-subscribe

I created a custom module to work with the message stack and votingapi.
My goal is to send a notification to the author when an entity is voted.

When the node is voted the notification goes to the node author successfully.
But unfortunately the same thing does not work for comment author.

When a comment is voted, a notification is sent to another member(uid) instead of the comment author.
What am I missing?
Thanks...

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Primary module hooks for Jasy custom module.
 */

use Drupal\comment\Entity\Comment;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityBase;
use Drupal\message\Entity\Message;
use Drupal\message_subscribe\Subscribers\DeliveryCandidate;
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;
use Drupal\user\Entity\User;
use Drupal\votingapi\Entity\Vote;

/**
 * Implements hook_vote_insert().
 */
function jasy_custom_module_vote_insert(Vote $vote) {
  $notifier = \Drupal::service('message_notify.sender');
  // Create a message for the node author.
  if ($vote->getVotedEntityType() == 'node') {
    $node = $vote->get('entity_id')->first()->get('entity')->getTarget()->getValue();
    $message = Message::create(['template' => 'node_owner_vote_notification', 'uid' => $node->getOwnerId()]);
    $message->set('field_node_reference', $node);
    $message->set('field_published', $node->isPublished());
    $message->set('field_vote_reference', $vote);
    $message->save();
    // Immediately notify message creator (node author) about new vote.
    $notifier->send($message, [], 'email');
  }
  // Create a message for the comment author.
  if ($vote->getVotedEntityType() == 'comment') {
    $comment = $vote->get('entity_id')->first()->get('entity')->getTarget()->getValue();
    $message = Message::create(['template' => 'comment_owner_vote_notification', 'uid' => $comment->getOwnerId()]);
    $message->set('field_comment_reference', $comment);
    $message->set('field_published', $comment->isPublished());
    $message->set('field_vote_reference', $vote);
    $message->save();
    // Immediately notify message creator (comment author) about new vote.
    $notifier->send($message, [], 'email');
  }
}

/**
 * Set message entity published field when it changes in the related entity.
 *
 * @param \Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityBase $entity
 *   The entity object.
 */
function jasy_custom_module_update_message_status(ContentEntityBase $entity) {

  if (!empty($entity->original) && $entity->isPublished() == $entity->original->isPublished()) {
    return;
  }
  $query = \Drupal::entityQuery('message');
  $field = 'field_' . $entity->getEntityType()->id() . '_reference';
  $query->condition($field . '.target_id', $entity->id());

  $results = $query->execute();
  if (empty($results)) {
    return;
  }
  $messages = Message::loadMultiple($results);
  foreach ($messages as $message) {
    $message->set('field_published', $entity->isPublished());
    $message->save();
  }
}
```